# Google Cloud SQL - ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, command-line-interface, ip-address, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my Google Cloud SQL using the command line.
I can successfully connect when at home and I set a static IP address. However, I have to be on the road the next few days and I can't be at home. I am hoping to connect to `mysql` and make changes as needed on the server through the `hotspot` on my phone, but I would be happy with any type of internet connection working.  How can I connect to my Google Cloud SQL even though I keep getting error as,

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL on server ...

1. I tried creating a Google Compute Engine VM instance and setting a static IP address and connection to `mysql` through that, but it doesn't work.
2. I make sure everytime to authorize the appropriate IP address, I am connecting from.

I am scratching my head and cannot figure out why it won't let me connect but at home even though I authorize all other IP address I have ever tried to connect from.

Comment: The instructions on how to connect from GCE are [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/gce-access). Note that you need to authorize the external IP of the VM. Is that what you were trying?

Comment: I have authorized the external IP and still get this error.  That is why is confusing.  I even did the catch all 0.0.0.0/0 that they mention and it still didn't work.

Comment: Connecting through a GCE instance should work if you have added the IP of the **GCE instance** in the Allowed Netowrks list. Are you getting the same errfor as before or is it different?
Can you try adding an allowed network with the GCE instance IP and then from the command prompt, run the following command: 
`mysql --host=cloud_sql_IP --user=my_user --password`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for whatever reason, I was able to connect if I requested an IPv4 address (costs $0.01 an hour) and used that to connect instead of the free IPv6 address, then I could connect from anywhere.  Otherwise I can only connect to my Cloud SQL when it is using the free IPv6 address at home.  Check out the screen shot below to see which button to press on Cloud SQL Page > Access Control > IP addresses  in order to request an IPv4 address and be able to connect with that IP address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138866/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-xxx-xxx-xx-xx-10060).

Use `gcloud sql connect [instance-name] --user=root` to allow your local machine IP.